# how can i display components in GUI server without a connected client?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have a tabbed Jframe named Version3 which implements Runnable. Into it i have 3 JPanels in different tabbs.Next to those tabs i have a textarea. 
I want my GUI to listen for messages and display them in the textarea. I tried to make my GUI Version3 a server which listens all the time in case it receives any message from client.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
          Version3 v=new Version3();
          v.setVisible(true);
          v.listenTo();
      }
});
```

I made my GUI Version3 a server but when i run the program the components of the GUI doesn't show until it's connected to client.I just have a blank GUI window with no components. Any ideas how to display all my components on my GUI without a client connected?

Comment: Show how do you construct your GUI? post a `sscce` for better help.

Answer (score 1):

> I made my GUI Version3 a server but when i run the program the
>   components of the GUI doesn't show until it's connected to client.I
>   just have a blank GUI window with no components. Any ideas how to
>   display all my components on my GUI without a client connected?

I think it's more than likely that you're blocking the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (a.k.a. EDT) while your class is trying to connect to the client. That's the reason why it works when you have connection but it doesn't when you haven't. The EDT is a single and special thread where Swing component creation and updates take place. If you have a heavy task running in the EDT then your GUI will freeze and Swing components won't be able to work (or even display).

Take a look to [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) trail to learn about concurrency in Swing.

Off-topic: please consider add your code in future questions. As @alex2410 suggested it's better if you include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Server:**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Server extends JPanel {

    Socket socket;
    final static int PORT = 2325;
    PrintWriter pr;
    public ServerSocket serverSocket;
    JButton btn_sendHello;
    int counter;

    Thread thread;

    public Server() {

        counter = 0;
        btn_sendHello = new JButton("Send hello");
        btn_sendHello.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (pr != null) {
                    pr.println("Hello from server " + ++counter);
                }
            }
        });

        this.add(btn_sendHello);

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
           thread = new Thread(waitingClient);
           thread.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    Runnable waitingClient = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                openStreams();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };

    private void openStreams() {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                pr = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("Server");
                frame.add(new Server());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(250, 100);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Client extends JPanel {

    final static int PORT = 2325;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader fromServer;
    private JTextField jtfield;
    Thread threadReceive;

    public Client() {
        jtfield = new JTextField(12);
        this.add(jtfield);

        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
            openStreams();
            Thread thread = new Thread(receives);
            thread.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    Runnable receives = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        processServerInput();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void openStreams() {
        try {
            if (socket != null) {
                fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void processServerInput() {
        try {
            String line = fromServer.readLine();
            while (!(line.equals("Bye"))) {
                jtfield.setText(line);
                line = fromServer.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    void closeStreams() {
        try {
            fromServer.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("Client");
                frame.add(new Client());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(250, 100);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```